# How do you "delete.().where" when using multiple columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Thank you in advance.  I am trying delete using using multiple columns.  I have tried the code below, but none of these work.

```py
delete = Material_table.delete().where(Material_table.c.Material_ID==current_material and Material_table.c.Batch_Suffix==current_batch_suffix)

delete = Material_table.delete().where(Material_table.c.Material_ID==current_material, Material_table.c.Batch_Suffix==current_batch_suffix)

delete = Material_table.delete().where(values=dict(Material_ID=current_material, Batch_Suffix=current_batch_suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds your query:

```
q = Material_table.delete(
    Material_table.c.Material_ID==current_material
    and Material_table.c.Batch_Suffix==current_batch_suffix
)
# but I prefer
q = Material_table.delete(and_(
    Material_table.c.Material_ID==current_material,
    Material_table.c.Batch_Suffix==current_batch_suffix,
))
# you can try to:
print(q)
```

But now you have to execute the query, which depends on your setup.
You may have a connection or session or you may even have the engine
bound to the metadata.

```
# one of these might work:
connection.execute(q)
session.execute(q)
q.execute()
```